# Wordpress custom post type logic

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created 2 custom post types (Movies and Actors), each one with multiple custom fields.

For Actors i have 3 custom fields (Details, History, Filmography) and i would like to display each custom field on a new page.

From the page /actor/%actorname%/ i will have 3 links:

- www.domain.com/actor/%actorname%/details
- www.domain.com/actor/%actorname%/history
- www.domain.com/actor/%actorname%/filmography

What is the logic behind this? How can this be done?

Do i create these pages first and then manipulate the template?
Any help would be great, i have no idea where to start from with this.

Comment: Yes your are right...
First add your 3 pages in `wp-admin` and than manipulate the template...Thats the simple way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is give an id to each actor.
For example Id for actor Brad Pitt is 1 and it is saved in your database.

then whenever a user clicks the name of the actor, which you can put as a hyperlink , and you can redirect the user to

```
$actor_id = //retrive the id from the database
<a href="www.example.com/actor/history/?id=$actor_id">Bradd Pitt </a>
```

then you create a template

```
<?php
/*
** Template Name: view actor history template 
*/
?>
<?php
$actor_id = $_GET['id'];
// retrieve data from database , that is history of the actor as
"SELECT history FROM table_actor WHERE id = $actor_id"


?>
// your html tags here
```

Also in your dashboard you create a new page and use the "view actor history template " instead of default template and note the page slug...
you use that slug in the " `<a href="www.example.com/actor/page-slug">Actor name </a>`"

Comment: i shouldn't need to query the db, i can just use $post->ID to retrieve actor's ID.

Comment: Finally went with your approach. /actor/history/?id=[$post->ID] which i set from the actor page. in the template i GET['id'] , get_post('id') and call my value.

Answer (score 0):

or simply add a page called archive-postname (name of custom posttype) and that will display as the default page for that custom post type

you can use the archive.php page as a starting point for this

Comment: saves you making templates and having to select them - its easier to use the hierarchy

Comment: adding an archive will display all my actors, that doesn't answer my question, showing custom fields value on separate pages.

Comment: ah sorry - then on each new page you create, you would simply list all the posts but only add in the relevant fields in your template. - for example a standard posts page has the post title, author, content etc - if your field is called filmography then just call in that particular field on that page and omit the others